# Concatenating large string in C to write to file

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I am new to C so I am having a tough time figuring this out. I'm reading file 500 bytes at a time, counting the number of lines in the file, and then once I get to 500 lines I am writing that to another file. The file is not coming out correctly at all and I think it has to do with my trying to concatenate a long string before writing it to the file. Here is the main loop of the code I have now:

```
   while (lineCount != 500)
   {
    if (lineCount == 500)
      break;
    readbytes = read(infd, buf, 500);
    for (str = buf; *str; ++str)
    {
      lineCount += *str == '\n';
      char *newPtr = realloc(forkBuf, (strlen(forkBuf) + strlen(str) + 2));
      forkBuf = newPtr;
      char* newFork = realloc(forkBuf, (strlen(forkBuf) + strlen(str) + 2));
      sprintf(forkBuf, "%s%s", newFork, str);
      if (lineCount == 500)
        break;
    }
    if (lineCount < 500)
    {
      if(readbytes < 500){
        write(outfd, forkBuf, (strlen(forkBuf) + 2));
        break;
      }
      continue;
    }
    write(outfd, forkBuf, (strlen(forkBuf) + 2));
  }
```

Comment: Why are you writing code like `lineCount += *str == '\n';`? Does this make things a bit difficult to read?

Comment: How is `if (lineCount == 500)` is going to be true considering the `while` statement above

Comment: I know that part could definitely be more readable. And for the if statement is only there because I have gone through many different changes trying to figure out this problem. Will need some clean up once working

Comment: I can only think of about 5,287 string concatenation examples already on StackOverflow. The length is irrelevant as long as you do not exhaust system memory.

Comment: Note that `read()` does not get a string; it gets an array of bytes which is not necessarily null terminated.  Indeed, it usually is not null terminated.  You should keep track of the actual lengths of the byte buffers, and use memory functions (`memmove()`, `memcpy()`, etc) and not string functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the two lines of code:

```
char* newFork = realloc(forkBuf, (strlen(forkBuf) + strlen(str) + 2));
sprintf(forkBuf, "%s%s", newFork, str);
```

This results in undefined behaviour; if `realloc` reallocates to a new address, `forkBuf` is left pointing at freed memory; even if `realloc` works in place, [according to the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc):

> The original pointer `ptr` [*`forkBuf` in this example*] is invalidated and any access to it is undefined behavior (even if reallocation was in-place).

I'd also add that if (as would probably happen) `forkBuf` equals `newFork`, using `sprintf` to copy a string to itself is also undefined behaviour.

Furthermore, you have a `for` loop here with `str` being treated as a single character, basically. I'd rewrite the whole loop, but a quick hack might be:

```
// One byte extra for the `\0`, and one for the new character
char *newPtr = realloc(forkBuf, (strlen(forkBuf) + 2));
if (newPtr == NULL)
    panic(); // Or whatever error handling you might want
forkBuf = newPtr;
size_t len = strlen(forkBuf);
forkBuf[len] = *str;
forkBuf[len + 1] = '\0';
```

Note you only need one `realloc()` in the loop, or better, a single `realloc(forkBuf, (strlen(forkBuf) + strlen(str) + 2));` outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you! It works great for files that have more than 500 lines! I cannot get it to work with a file with less than 500 lines though, I am not sure but it is adding multiple extra lines to the end. Thank you so much for your help though!